# Retrieving date that a value was updated?

Tags: sql

I want to be able to retrieve the date that a value was updated. Is this possible? We have a training database and people eventually go inactive when they leave our organisation. But this is just a simple boolean column. I was hoping to use a WHERE statement that only retrieves values that are 'inactive' and where this value was only updated after a certain date?

Is that possible?

Comment: anything is possible!... if you've designed for it... Otherwise, it's a good time to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you're recording the date somewhere.

That said, you might be able to access the transaction log.  See here: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/View-SQL-Server-transaction-logs-using-DBCC

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot determine the last time the value of a specific column in a row was last updated. In order to do this, you need to maintain a modified column on your table. To help you enforce that column is always set properly, you could create a trigger to update it when ever the inactive column is modified.